# Unable to launch selenium with python in mac

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, selenium, pydev

I'm facing an issue with selenium with python in Mac OS..
**Python 2.7
pydev 3.0**

My sample code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.formsite.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.close()
```

Installed selenium using PIP

```
pip install selenium
Downloading/unpacking selenium
  Downloading selenium-2.44.0.tar.gz (2.6MB): 2.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/qw/ctlmndfd5ts9w2p6v1qc382r0000gn/T/pip_build_bhanusaa/selenium/setup.py) egg_info for package selenium

Installing collected packages: selenium
  Running setup.py install for selenium

Successfully installed selenium
```

Assigned `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in Python Path library
[image]

**getting below error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bhanusaa/Desktop/samp/src/scripts/new.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 65, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 88, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env).communicate()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please check here for solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570003/python-webdriver-from-selenium

Comment: the link you provided is about python unittest frame work, (even when i tried the code in the link you had provided results in same error) i'm getting "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Answer (score -1):

HI the issue is resolved now, previously i had installed Firefox 34.0 in my Mac and now downgraded to 30.0, now it is working fine.